# How to search for objects in a specific direction in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and created an object, let's say a car. Now I want to know the distance to the next object in a specific direction, for example in front of it or at 45 degrees. 
What I want to archieve is comparable to the car sending light rays in the direction measuring the distance to the next collider.

What I can think of is checking for all objects in the scene, but hopefully there is a better solution.

Comment: At first thought, you could attach a collider which would encapsulate the "headlights".  When OnTrigger is called you could raycast to the object to see if it is actually within your 45 degree field of view.

Comment: Isn’t that what circlecast is for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your looking for [Physics.Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html).

This creates a line from point a (origin) to point b (origin + direction * maxDistance). The documentation has a nice example.

maxDistance would only return object in that range.
You can do multiple ray casts adding rotation to the direction your rays to get a wider scan. [Physics.OverlapSphere](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html) is also an option, it checks a full sphere around a location for anything that overlapse. You would need to then check if the angle between the car and the object is in your range by calculating the angle between the 2 positions.

Comment: Thanks! I wouldn't have found this on my own.